# How to replace particular string in table column value in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I am trying to replace certain text with other text in PostgreSQL.

To be more specific, I am trying to **replace image path and anchor href** in `article` (table `blog_posts`) from relative to absolute path. Some of the images and anchors already have an absolute path that should not get disturbed.

**I tried to select the records which I need to modify:**

```
SELECT
  bp.id,
  bp.article,
FROM
  blog_posts bp
WHERE
  bp.article LIKE '%src=%"/fixed_word/%' 
  OR  
  bp.article LIKE '%src="/fixed_word/%'
 OR
 bp.article LIKE '%href="/fixed_word/%'
 OR
 bp.article LIKE '%href=%"/fixed_word/%'
```

now I am not sure how to proceed further to update. Please help to get right solution.

**My data is something like this:**

**MyTable**: `blog_posts`

```
id article
1  any text <img any-atribute src="/fixed_word/variable_word1/something.png"/> any text
2  any text <a any-attribute href="/fixed_word/variable_word2/something2.png"><img src="/fixed_word/variable_word2/something2.png"/> </a>any text
3  any text <img src="https://mydomain.subdomain.com/fixed_word/variable_word1/something.png"/> any text
4  any text <img any-attribute src=\"/fixed_word/variable_word1/something.png"/> any text
5  any text <a any-attribute href=\"/fixed_word/variable_word2/something2.png"><img src=\"/fixed_word/variable_word2/something2.png"/> </a>any text
6  any text <img any-attribute src="https://mydomain.subdomain.com/fixed_word/variable_word6/something6.png"/> any text
```

OutPut should be:

```
id article
1  any text <img any-atribute src="https://mydomain.subdomain.com/fixed_word/variable_word1/something.png"/> any text
2  any text <a any-attribute href="https://mydomain.subdomain.com/fixed_word/variable_word2/something2.png"><img src="https://mydomain.subdomain.com/fixed_word/variable_word2/something2.png"/> </a>any text
3  any text <img src="https://mydomain.subdomain.com/fixed_word/variable_word1/something.png"/> any text
4  any text <img any-attribute src="https://mydomain.subdomain.com/fixed_wordvariable_word1/something.png"/> any text
5  any text <a any-attribute href="https://mydomain.subdomain.com/fixed_word/variable_word2/something2.png">
6  any text <img any-attribute src="https://mydomain.subdomain.com/fixed_word/variable_word6/something6.png"/> any text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a starting point:

```
UPDATE blog_posts
SET article = regexp_replace(
                 article,
                 E'(src|href)=[^"]*"/fixed_word/([^"]*)',
                 E'\\1="https://mydomain.subdomain.com/fixed_word/\\2',
                 'g'
              )
WHERE article ~ E'(src|href)=[^"]*"/fixed_word/([^"]*)';
```

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I again checked the possible bad data for the ` \ ` used in src or href path. fortunately there is not such data. so there is no worry about '\' there will be always ' / ' in src or href. but there might be that starting '/' in `src=/"\fixed_word...` Accordingly I need the help, I will be changing the question details for the same. Sorry for inconvenience!

Comment: Error:  parentheses () not balanced

Comment: My statement works for your example, there are no unbalanced parentheses. Could it be that you need to escape certain special characters in string constants in the programming language you are using?

Comment: No, I am running directly in PostgreSQL SQL editor.

Comment: I have never heard of "SQL editor", but maybe your problem is there. You could try `psql`. You can count the parentheses, and you will see they are balanced.

Comment: I am using SQL Manager for PostgreSQL in that we have the option to execute SQL ( F12 key opens it ). I have manually checked the parentheses that look good, still, there is an error.

Comment: I can only recommend that you use a tool that doesn't reject valid SQL.

Comment: Ok. so here is the error now for the regular expression: WARNING:  nonstandard use of \\ in a string literal. Use the escape string syntax for backslashes, e.g., E'\\'.

Comment: I do not good that much in regular expressions, might be this error is easy to solve

Comment: I have modified the RE as: `(src|href)=[^"]*"[/\]fixed_word[/\]([^"]*)` and it is worked. any scenario I am missing ?

Comment: Ugh. Are you using a really very old version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.5

Comment: If you have `standard_conforming_strings = off`, you need to double all backslashes. I'll edit the answer accordingly. But you should really use `standard_conforming_strings = on`.

Comment: Your answer working, but I have tried it `[\\/]` instead of `[/\\]` before your answer and it is also working so I am confused. I need to send this query to my technical product manager for approval!

Comment: I have removed all the backslashes since you don't need them. This simplifies the code. You should test it thoroughly before using it, since I won't guarantee correctness.

Comment: Thank you! The answer is accepted. Got to learn something new in my career path :-)